# Laravel echo server - Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

I'm trying to setup Laravel echo server for my real time chat application,I am following this tutorial https://medium.com/@dennissmink/laravel-echo-server-how-to-24d5778ece8b , I have setup and installed the Laravel echo server package, but when I run `laravel-echo-server start`, it always brings the error below, Please what may be wrong

[image]

Comment: have you found a solutions for that error?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet

Comment: It worked for me when I choose not to run it in development mode!

Comment: Check config for data, which you specified during init sequence. In my case I answered "y" (yes) on "Which port..." question and it caused exactly same error

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error having wrong value on "port": "y", so, I suggest to check carefully laravel-echo-server.json file.

Comment: You're new here, try to provide a more in-depth answer to help OP a bit more. For example, what should he be looking for in that file? Something specific?

Answer (score 1):

Here how it worked for me,

I was setting "authHost": "http://localhost:8000" in laravel-echo-server.json file

you can do this also after you run laravel-echo-server init and provide the URL there.

so the port was the culprit there.

the solution was to just map the URL.

like I use laravel valet so I mapped my website to something.test

then the URL in my laravel-echo-server file to "authHost": "http://something.test"

then I ran laravel-echo-server start and It worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you have run the command laravel-echo-server init... on PORT you have mentioned **Yes** instead of enter key. This lead the problem.

Just run the command laravel-echo-server init --while on port option either mention a port number or just enter.